# In Android, I need to get data via TCP in an onDraw() method

Tags: java, android, multithreading

As the title describes, I have a View class in which I need to reach out to get some data via TCP before I update the drawing.  When I implemented this in my usual new Thread()...start() construction Eclipse whined at me about instantiating something new in an onDraw() method.  In response to that, I reconfigured my thread as a class variable and I'm attempt to execute t.start() in the onDraw() loop.

However, there must be some thread baby-sitting I'm not aware about because my code is throwing an exception (java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started) when it attempts to start the thread the second time.  The following is the current version of my code:

```
Thread t = new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            String st1 = getNetwork();          //  Get network information
            if (null != st1)
            {
                String[] st = st1.substring (st1.indexOf (' ') + 1, st1.length()).split (",+");
                setNeighbors (st.length);

                for (String s:st)
                {
                    Log.e (TAG, s.trim());

                    String[] t1 = s.trim().split ("\\s+");
                    numbers.add     (t1[0]);
                    addresses.add   (t1[1]);
                    states.add      (t1[2]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
        finally
        {
            NetworkView.this.wait = false;
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDraw (final Canvas canvas)
{
    if (++drawCtr % 300 == 0)
    {
        this.wait = true;

        t.start();
        while (wait);

        try
        {
            t.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { }
    }

    update (canvas);

    try { Thread.sleep (50); }
    catch (InterruptedException e) { }

    invalidate();
}
```

I get that the 2nd time around, my thread has already been started.  How do I "reset" or "unstart" it for a 2nd attempt??

Comment: Not a good idea to do all this in `onDraw`. It should run as fast as possible as it will be called 60 times a second.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting the idea that I want to spin off the getting information task into it's own independent thread, and let the onDraw() method use whatever information is available at the time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Henry pointed out, my initial concept was a bad idea.  A much more workable architecture was to have the TCP thread control the redraw, rather than having the redraw thread control the TCP data exchange, especially because there's no need (at least in my case) to redraw the screen between TCP updates.  Hence, I implemented this thread in my View object's constructor:

```
(new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        while (looping)
        {
            try
            {
                //  Get the important data via TCP (CAN'T be on the UI thread)

                String st1 = tcpClient.getNetwork();
                String st2 = tcpClient.getDiscovery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    //  Redraw the display (HAS TO be on the UI thread)
                    net.runOnUiThread (new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            invalidate();
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }

                try { Thread.sleep (2000); }
                catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

The key is the invalidate() call in the finally block (that needs to be run on the UI thread).  That will update the screen based on the fresh new information.